# Creating image from function in parallel

Tags: image, haskell

I'm writting a parogram in Haskell that creates a fractal and writes to a PNG file. I have a function

```
f:: Int->Int->PixelRGB8
```

which calcualtes color of the pixel with given image coordinates. (The output color format, PixelRGB8, is not important, I can easilly change it to, say, RGB tuple or anything).

Using Codec.Picture, I can write

```
writePng "test.png" $ generateImage f width height
```

which indeed writes the desired image file. However, it works very slowly and I can see that my CPU load is low. I want to use parallel computations, since the computation of each pixel value does not depend on its neighbors. As far as I can see, Codec.Picture does not provide any means to do it. I understand how parMap works, but I can't see a way to apply it here. I think one possible solution  is to use repa.DevIL, but I'm kinda lost in its multidimusional arrays notation which looks like an overkill in my case. So, the question is: how to construct an image file from given function using parallel?

**UPDATE**. Here's a complete code (function 'extract' is ommited because it's long and called only one time):

```
import Data.Complex
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import Codec.Picture

eval:: (Floating a) => [a] -> a -> a
eval [p] _    = p
eval (p:ps) z = p * z ** (fromIntegral (length ps) ) + (eval ps z)

type Comp = Complex Double

-- func, der, z, iter
convergesOrNot:: (Comp -> Comp) -> (Comp -> Comp) -> Comp->Int -> Int
convergesOrNot _ _ _ 0 = 0
convergesOrNot f d z iter | realPart (abs (f z) ) < 1e-6 = 1
              | otherwise = convergesOrNot f d (z - (f z)/(d z)) (iter-1)

-- x, y, f,d, xMin, xMin, stepX, stepY
getPixel:: Int->Int->(Comp->Comp)->(Comp->Comp)->Double->Double->Double->Double->PixelRGB8
getPixel x y f d xMin yMin stepX stepY | convergesOrNot f d z 16 == 1 = PixelRGB8 255 255 255
                       | otherwise = PixelRGB8 0 0 0
    where
        real = xMin + (fromIntegral x)*stepX
        imag = yMin + (fromIntegral y)*stepY
        z = real :+ imag; 

data Params = Params{f :: [Comp],
             d :: [Comp],
             xMin::Double,
             yMin::Double,
             stepX::Double,
             stepY::Double,
             width::Int,
             height::Int        
            } deriving (Show)

getPixelParams:: Int->Int->Params->PixelRGB8
getPixelParams x y params = getPixel x y func derv (xMin params) (yMin params) (stepX params) (stepY params)
    where
        func = \z -> eval (f params) z
        derv = \z -> eval (d params) z

main = do
    handle <- openFile "config.txt" ReadMode
    config <- hGetContents handle
    let params = extract config
    writePng "test.png" $ generateImage (\x y -> getPixelParams x y params) (width params) (height params)
    hClose handle
```

The profiling shows that most of the time is spent in eval function. Result (the .prof file ) is as follows (it's only the top part of file, the rest is bunch of zeroes):

```
COST CENTRE                                       MODULE                               no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                                              MAIN                                  91           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                                             Main                                 183           0    0.0    0.0    99.9  100.0
  main.\                                          Main                                 244           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   getPixelParams                                 Main                                 245           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    getPixelParams.derv                           Main                                 269           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    getPixelParams.func                           Main                                 246           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  generateImage                                   Codec.Picture.Types                  199           1    0.0    0.0    99.8   99.9
   generateImage.generated                        Codec.Picture.Types                  234           1    0.0    0.0    99.8   99.9
    generateImage.generated.lineGenerator         Codec.Picture.Types                  238         257    0.0    0.0    99.8   99.9
     generateImage.generated.lineGenerator.column Codec.Picture.Types                  239       65792    0.5    0.8    99.8   99.9
      unsafeWritePixel                            Codec.Picture.Types                  275       65536    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
      main.\                                      Main                                 240       65536    0.1    0.0    99.2   99.1
       getPixelParams                             Main                                 241       65536    0.7    0.0    99.1   99.1
        getPixelParams.derv                       Main                                 270           0    0.2    0.0    19.3   18.5
         getPixelParams.derv.\                    Main                                 271      463922    0.2    0.0    19.2   18.5
          eval                                    Main                                 272     1391766   18.9   18.5    18.9   18.5
        getPixelParams.func                       Main                                 247           0    0.5    0.0    62.3   59.0
         getPixelParams.func.\                    Main                                 248      993380    0.4    0.0    61.8   59.0
          eval                                    Main                                 249     3973520   61.4   59.0    61.4   59.0
        getPixel                                  Main                                 242       65536    0.2    0.0    16.7   21.5
         getPixel.imag                            Main                                 262         256    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
         getPixel.z                               Main                                 261       65536    0.1    0.1     0.1    0.1
         getPixel.real                            Main                                 251       65536    0.2    0.1     0.2    0.1
         convergesOrNot                           Main                                 243      531889   16.3   21.3    16.3   21.3
```

**UPDATE 2** After a number of changes from @Cirdec and @Jedai, the code looks like this:

```
import Data.Complex
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import qualified Data.List as DL 

import Codec.Picture
import Codec.Picture.Types

import Control.Parallel
import Data.Array
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)

class Ix a => Partitionable a where
    partition :: Int -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)]

    default partition :: (Num a) => Int -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
    partition n r@(l,_) = zipWith (\x y -> (x, x+y-1)) starts steps
        where
            (span, longerSpans) = rangeSize r `quotRem` n
            steps = zipWith (+) (replicate (min (rangeSize r) n) (fromIntegral span)) (replicate longerSpans 1 ++ repeat 0)
            starts = scanl (+) l steps

instance Partitionable Int

instance (Partitionable a, Partitionable b) => Partitionable (a, b) where
    partition n ((x0,y0), (x1, y1)) = do
        xr'@(x0', x1') <- partition n (x0, x1)
        let n' = n * rangeSize xr' `div` rangeSize (x0, x1)
        (y0', y1') <- partition n' (y0, y1)
        return ((x0', y0'), (x1', y1'))       

mkArrayPar :: (Partitionable i) => Int -> Strategy e -> (i, i) -> (i -> e) -> Array i e
mkArrayPar n s bounds f = listArray bounds (concat workUnits)
    where
        partitions = partition n bounds
        workUnits  = parMap (evalList s) (map f . range) partitions

generateImagePar :: forall a . Pixel a  => (Int -> Int -> a) -> Int -> Int -> Image a
generateImagePar f w h = generateImage f' w h
    where
        bounds = ((0, 0), (w-1,h-1))
        pixels = mkArrayPar numCapabilities rseq bounds (uncurry f)
        f'     = curry (pixels !)

--
--  Newton
--
eval:: (Floating a) => [a] -> a -> a
eval cs z = DL.foldl1' (\acc c -> acc * z + c) cs

diff:: (Floating a) => [a] -> [a]
diff [p] = []
diff (p:ps) =  [(fromIntegral (length ps) )*p] ++ diff ps

type Comp = Complex Double

convergesOrNot:: (Comp -> Comp) -> (Comp -> Comp) -> Comp->Int -> Int
convergesOrNot _ _ _ 0 = 0
convergesOrNot f d z iter | realPart (abs (f z) ) < 1e-6 = 1
              | otherwise = convergesOrNot f d (z - (f z)/(d z)) (iter-1)

-- x, y, f,d, xMin, xMin, stepX, stepY
getPixel:: Int->Int->(Comp->Comp)->(Comp->Comp)->Double->Double->Double->Double->PixelRGB8
getPixel x y f d xMin yMin stepX stepY | convergesOrNot f d z 16 == 1 = PixelRGB8 255 255 255
                       | otherwise = PixelRGB8 0 0 0
    where
        real = xMin + (fromIntegral x)*stepX
        imag = yMin + (fromIntegral y)*stepY
        z = real :+ imag; 

data Params = Params{f :: [Comp],
             d :: [Comp],
             xMin::Double,
             yMin::Double,
             stepX::Double,
             stepY::Double,
             width::Int,
             height::Int        
            } deriving (Show)

extract:: String -> Params
extract config = Params poly deriv xMin yMin stepX stepY width height
    where 
        lines = splitOn "\n" config
        wh = splitOn " " (lines !! 0) 
        width  = read (wh !! 0) :: Int
        height = read (wh !! 1) :: Int
        bottomLeft = splitOn " " (lines !! 1)
        upperRight = splitOn " " (lines !! 2)
        xMin = read $ (bottomLeft !! 0) :: Double
        yMin = read $ (bottomLeft !! 1) :: Double
        xMax = read $ (upperRight !! 0) :: Double
        yMax = read $ (upperRight !! 1) :: Double
        stepX = (xMax - xMin)/(fromIntegral width)
        stepY = (yMax - yMin)/(fromIntegral height)     
        poly = map (\x -> (read x :: Double) :+ 0) (splitOn " " (lines !! 3))
        deriv = diff poly

getPixelParams:: Int->Int->Params->PixelRGB8
getPixelParams x y params = getPixel x y func derv (xMin params) (yMin params) (stepX params) (stepY params)
    where
        func = \z -> eval (f params) z
        derv = \z -> eval (d params) z

main = do
    handle <- openFile "config.txt" ReadMode
    config <- hGetContents handle
    let params = extract config
    writePng "test.png" $ generateImagePar (\x y -> getPixelParams x y params) (width params) (height params)
    hClose handle
```

I compile it with

```
ghc O2  -threaded  -rtsopts -XDefaultSignatures -XExistentialQuantification partNewton.hs -o newton
```

and I run it with `./newton +RTS -N`. But when I run it on config

```
2048 2048
-1 -1
1 1
1 0 0 1
```

it results in error

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
```

Comment: I would suggest profiling as a first step maybe ? Because I don't really see why this would be so slow except if `generateImage` was very hard to optimize (you *are* compiling this with -O2, right ?) or your `f` was doing some strange business (can you show its code ?).

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling with O2, I've found it to have tremendious deffrence) I've included code and profiling results to the post.

Comment: What are the contents of `config.txt`? How large are the polynomials for `eval`? You may be spending a lot of time computing the degree over and over again (`fromIntegral (length ps)`).

Comment: It's really small:

256 256 '\n'

-1 -1 '\n'

1 1 '\n'

1 0 0 1 '\n'


i.e, is 256x256 pixels, 3rd degree polynomial.

Comment: Cirdec, however, by replacing  "p * z ** (fromIntegral (length ps) )" with "p * (z ^ (length ps))" I've obtained 20% speedup. Tnanks for the idea!

Comment: `eval` is a classic, the efficient way to compute it is : `eval cs z = foldl' (\beg c -> beg * z + c) cs`. That should already help a lot.

Comment: Though if you really wanted something competitive, the way to go would probably be to start by compiling JIT your polynomials to function (with [llvm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general) for example).

Comment: Changing eval to `eval cs z = foldl1 (\beg c -> beg * z + c) cs` sped up things almost 30%, thank you! I do beleve that it should be `foldl1`, not `foldl'`, right? The CPU load is still low, though(

Comment: `foldl1'` rather than `foldl1` if you wish to be explicit on the strictness (it is vaguely possible that -O2 is already doing the right transformation but not certain, so it is better to use Data.List.foldl1' )

Comment: Changing from `foldl1'` to `foldl1` did not affect the perfomance, so I guess O2 really does that as you say.

Comment: What version of ghc are you using? On my machine with ghc 7.8.3, your update 2 code runs for images up to at least 5020x5020 without overflowing the stack, even with the stack size set to only 8 megabytes with `+RTS -k8M`. (You can compile in the `-N` option with `-with-rtsopts=-N`).

Comment: I'm using  7.4.1.  I was able to run 2048x2048 with -k8M, it took almost 10 minutes, yet the CPU was loaded so I guess the parallelesation was succesfull) Strange though that 8M is very close to default value and yet it's enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the pixels in parallel before generating the image. To make the pixel lookup for `generateImage` simple, we'll stuff all of the pixels into an [`Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Array
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
```

To generate the image in parallel, we'll calculate the pixels in parallel for each boint within the [`range`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#v:range) of the `bounds` of the image. We'll build a temporary `Array` to hold all the pixels. The array's lookup function, [`!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:-33-) will provide an efficient lookup function to pass to `generateImage`.

```
generateImagePar :: forall a . Pixel a  => (Int -> Int -> a) -> Int -> Int -> Image a
generateImagePar f w h = generateImage f' w h
    where
        bounds     = ((0, 0), (w-1,h-1))
        pixels     = parMap rseq (uncurry f) (range bounds)
        pixelArray = listArray bounds pixels
        f'         = curry (pixelArray !)
```

We can then write your example in terms of `generateImagePar`.

```
writePng "test.png" $ generateImagePar f width height
```

This may be no faster and may in fact be slower than using `generateImage`. It's important to profile your code to understand *why* it is slow before attempting to improve its performance. For example, if your program is memory starved or is thrashing resources, using `generateImagePar` will certainly be slower than using `generateImage`.

#### Partitioning the work

We can partition the work into chunks to reduce the number of sparks without resorting to any sort of mutable data structure. First we'll define the class of indexes whose ranges can be divided into partitions. We'll define a default for dividing up numeric ranges.

```
class Ix a => Partitionable a where
    partition :: Int -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)]

    default partition :: (Num a) => Int -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
    partition n r@(l,_) = zipWith (\x y -> (x, x+y-1)) starts steps
        where
            (span, longerSpans) = rangeSize r `quotRem` n
            steps = zipWith (+) (replicate (min (rangeSize r) n) (fromIntegral span)) (replicate longerSpans 1 ++ repeat 0)
            starts = scanl (+) l steps
```

`Int`s (and any other `Num`) can be made `Partitionable` using the default implementation.

```
instance Partitionable Int
```

Index products can be partitioned by first partitioning the first dimension, and then partitioning the second dimension if there aren't enough possible divisions in the first dimension.

```
instance (Partitionable a, Partitionable b) => Partitionable (a, b) where
    partition n ((x0,y0), (x1, y1)) = do
        xr'@(x0', x1') <- partition n (x0, x1)
        let n' = n * rangeSize xr' `div` rangeSize (x0, x1)
        (y0', y1') <- partition n' (y0, y1)
        return ((x0', y0'), (x1', y1'))
```

We can build an array in parallel by partitioning the work into units and sparking each work unit.

```
mkArrayPar :: (Partitionable i) => Int -> Strategy e -> (i, i) -> (i -> e) -> Array i e
mkArrayPar n s bounds f = listArray bounds (concat workUnits)
    where
        partitions = partition n bounds
        workUnits  = parMap (evalList s) (map f . range) partitions
```

Now we can define `generateImagePar` in terms of making an array in parallel. A good number of partitions is a small multiple of the number of actual processors, [`numCapabilities`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:numCapabilities); we'll start up to `1` partition per processor.

```
import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)

generateImagePar :: forall a . Pixel a  => (Int -> Int -> a) -> Int -> Int -> Image a
generateImagePar f w h = generateImage f' w h
    where
        bounds = ((0, 0), (w-1,h-1))
        pixels = mkArrayPar numCapabilities rseq bounds (uncurry f)
        f'     = curry (pixels !)
```

Comment: I've tried your code, it compiled but provided excatly the same work time as generateImage. I've added -threaded flag and run the program with +RTS -N, with diffrent Ns, and no change in perfomance was achived at all :( I'm running Core i7, so CPU should handle threads. Also I've added profiling results for my code to post.

Comment: Given that this code is creating one spark per pixel, I'm a bit surprised it doesn't do much worse than the original.... Almost certainly, the right way to proceed would only be to do this in chunks (by creating a `newMutableImage` and populating it with unsafe operations in several threads, of course with a safe encapsulation). But if you have to generate many images, the right course would simply be to generate several image in parallel rather than trying to generate each image in parallel...

Comment: I want to render one high-quality image (something like 5000x5000) rather than a series of images... Do I understand right that this `newMutableImage` should be inherited somehow from Codec's Image?

Comment: Inherited isn't the right word. `MutableImage` are another type from JuicyPixel that can be modified in-place (only in the ST monad though, to guarantee that any function that manipulate them internally will be pure externally). Read the code of [`generateImage`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.3/docs/src/Codec-Picture-Types.html#generateImage) and other similar functions to see how they could be used (or directly the mutable vector that are part of them).

Comment: @Month The work can be partitioned into a smaller number of pieces without resorting to using mutable data structures, see my updated answer. This incurs additional overhead (as does any parallelism); it might be less than the overhead of a spark per pixel In general, parallelizing code will only be advantageous when the cost of the work to be done dominates the cost of parallelism.

Comment: @Cirdec, I've run your code and increased the perfomance almost two times for images with sides from 256x256 to 1024x1024, with perfomance impoving more as image get bigger. However, when I try to run it on 2048x2048 image, it either fails with message `Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.` or tries to alloctae something like 3.5 Gb in RAM, after what the OS (Debian in my case) kills it. What can cause such huge memory consumption?

Comment: @Month I think I messed up `mkArrayPar`; it was still making too many sparks. There's a new `mkArrayPar` in the answer. All of the pixels have to be put into lists, which can be many times bigger than the array, the overhead from that might be too much. A quick estimate puts it at `(8+8+8+8+8)*2048*2048` bytes or about 160 megabytes for the lists.

Comment: @Cirdec thank you for an update, but the problem remains in the updated code: it fails on my PC on 2048x2048 images with `Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.`. However, now doesn't try to allocate huge amout of RAM)

Comment: @Month Can you update the code in the question with what you are using now (`eval`, any other changes you've made to the fractal part) and include either the problematic `Params` or `config.txt`?

Comment: @Cirdec, sure. I've update the post (**UPDATE 2**) with the new code based on your new `generateImagePar`.